# Check if array has no stored value yet

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to check if my array hasn't stored any data on the array yet then I'll write "No Data Yet" I tried `myArray.Length == 0` but it doesn't seem to work.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAr89.png)

```
using System;

namespace IntegMidTerm
{
    class Program
    {
        static String[] fName = new string[10];
        static long[] cNumber = new long[10];
        static String[] numbers = new string[10] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };
        static String fullName;
        static int i = 0, k = 0;
        static long contactNumber;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int optNum;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n---Welcome to my C# Phonebook Application---\n");
            Console.WriteLine("\tMain Menu" +
            "\n[1] Create New Contact" +
            "\n[2] View All Contancts" +
            "\n[3] Exit Application\n");

            Console.Write("Enter option number: ");
            optNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (optNum)
            {
                case 1:
                    createContact();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    displayContact();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using my application! Terminating program...");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void createContact()
    {
        Console.Write("\nEnter your full name: ");
        fullName = Console.ReadLine();
        fName[i] = fullName;
        i++;

        Console.Write("\nEnter your contact number: ");
        contactNumber = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
        cNumber[k] = contactNumber;
        k++;
    }

    public static void displayContact()
    {
        if (fName.Length == 0 && cNumber[i] == 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Data Yet!");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[j] + ". " + fName[i] + " - " + cNumber[k]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The above result I've shown is somewhat wrong it is because I haven't created new contact yet, then I press number 2 which will show the data stored but since I use if statement which is if array is empty or no data stored yet "No Data yet" will show. but in my case it shows the data.

Comment: `fName.Length` will never be 0 because you're declaring it as containing 10 items: `static String[] fName = new string[10];` Did you actually intend to check `fName[i].Length` like `cNumber[i]`?

Comment: Yes, I tried doing what you've said but it throw exception saying `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: If you haven't assigned a string value to `fName[i]`, then it will be the default value: `null`. Do you just want to check if it's `!= null`?

Comment: If you would like to check whether `fName` contains at least one item which is not null (`null` is the default value if the item is not set yet), so at least item was set to a new value in the array, you could check that with this: `bool containsNonNullItem = a.Count(s => s != null) != 0;` But if you set a value to null the bool will still say false, even though you set the items value, so it's not a perfect solution.

Comment: I think so, what I was trying to achieve is to check whether the array has a value or not if it has not value yet then it will display "No data yet" but in my case it's not working.

Comment: I declare 10 items, its because we were told to let the user input 10 data only.

Comment: The C#1.0 version to check array contents ( probably what is allowed at your level of learning) would be to use a for-loop over the array length and check that some or all positions hold a non-null value

Comment: As an aside, assuming that "Contact number" means something like "telephone number" don't use a type such as long/int to store it. A phone number is not an integral number. For this task I'd say just use a string.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using arrays, when an array is being initialized, its length will be constant. In your case, fName and cNumber will have a length of **10** always. If you would like to have dynamic length including zero, use List in C#. Like this:

```
static List<string> fName = new List<string>();
if (fName.Count == 0)
{
  // do something
}
// to add an item to list you can do:
fName.Add("john");
```

Comment: Does arraylist and list the same? We're only allowed to use arraylist or array depends on what we want to use so I tried using Array.

Comment: @Testtest Yes array list is almost the same as List. If you need more, see microsoft docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0

Comment: If your teacher is telling you to use arraylist, find a new teacher @Testtest.

Comment: @mjwills , She says if it is needed only so I use array to store the data.

Comment: @Testtest My point is that arraylist is a terrible type to suggest anyone should use. I would be upset if someone suggested it 10 years ago, let alone today.

Comment: `ArrayList` became obsolete as of C#2, when generics were introduced (in 2005); `List<T>` should be used instead.

Comment: oh I see why you're getting mad @mjwills my bad, I'm just doing the task that given to me. Anyway thanks for the information.

Comment: May I ask? One last, can I set the size of the arraylist to a fix size like. I want my arraylist to store only 10 data, just like I did in the code above I made.

Comment: @Testtest It can be _initialised_ to a specific size, but the whole purpose of that class is that it allows the size to be dynamic, which isn't possible with standard arrays. `ArrayList` (and `List<T>`) use arrays internally, so if you were to initialise to a specific size, it would prevent a new array from being allocated when items are added.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Can I do something like `if (myArrayList == 10)` the data will just show because I only allow user to input 10 data only.

Comment: Yes you can @Testtest if you check its length.

Comment: @mjwills Okay, might try it. Can't find any solution than this tho. XD